# Razor Pages - Add Meta Refresh Tag Dynamically

Tags: razor-pages

Using DotNetCore 2.2.

I would like to dynamically add a meta refresh to my Razor Page.

```
<head>
  ...
  <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="30">
</head>
```

i.e

```
public async Task OnGet()
{
    if (something) {
        // add the meta tag
    }
}
```

My _Layout is currently the default one for a new project.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe there is a more elegant way of doing this.

But I went for -

```
public async Task OnGet()
{
    if (something) {
        // add the meta tag
        ViewData["ShowMeta"] = _refreshSeconds.ToString();
    }
}
```

And in _Layout.cshtml

```
@if (ViewData["ShowMeta"] != null)
{
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="@ViewData["ShowMeta"]">
}
```